# Flutter: Saving data to an excel workbook

Tags: excel, flutter

Guys in my Flutter project I'm trying to save my data in Excel, and to do that I used 2 packages (each one alone) but got no advantage result!!!

Packages:

- excel 1.1.5
- syncfusion_flutter_xlsio 20.3.49-beta

for the second one there is a video in youtube describe the usage, I did it like the video but got no result!!!

my code:

```
Future createExcel() async {
    final Workbook workbook = Workbook();
    final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
    workbook.dispose();

    final Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
    sheet.getRangeByName('A1').setText('Subscribers');
    sheet.getRangeByName('B1').setText('Quantity');
    sheet.getRangeByName('C1').setText('Paid');
    sheet.getRangeByName('D1').setText('UnPaid');

    final String path = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
    final String fileName = '$path/Report.xlsx';
    final File file = File(fileName);
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    OpenFile.open(fileName);
  }
```

Also there is no error messages appears to me!!!

I searched for long time about any thing help this idea, but resources are to limited.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Update**
I'm using getx package, but despite that, I did changes without any progress!!

This is the function in class controller:

```
Future createExcel() async {
    final Workbook workbook = Workbook();

    final Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
    sheet.getRangeByName('A1').setText('Subscribers');
    sheet.getRangeByName('B1').setText('Quantity');
    sheet.getRangeByName('C1').setText('Paid');
    sheet.getRangeByName('D1').setText('UnPaid');

    final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
    workbook.dispose();

    final String path = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
    final String fileName = '$path/Report.xlsx';
    final File file = File(fileName);
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    OpenFile.open(fileName);
    update();
  }
```

And this is when I call it in UI class:

```
GetBuilder<DashboardController>(
                    builder: (controller) => AddSaveButton(
                      title: 'Extract excel',
                      fontSize: Dimensions.font24,
                      onPress: () {
                        controller.createExcel();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, the code after updating up in the post, It seems there is many open_file packages with problems..

When I tried many packages, one of them worked perfectly with me, so the code I putted in the update is working.

The package is: `open_file_plus: ^3.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `saveAsStream()` and `dispose()` too early, before adding anything to the worksheet.

Move these lines:

```
final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
workbook.dispose();
```

after this line:

```
sheet.getRangeByName('D1').setText('UnPaid');
```

Also, you should set `flush` to `true` when calling `writeAsBytes`:

```
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
```

I personally had some issues with the `OpenFile` package, it was updated 17 months ago. I ended up with using [this package instead](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex).

Comment: Unfortunatelly bro, it didn't work!!!
Also I replaced the OpenFile package with the package you mention, but the same thing
when I press the button that should open an excel sheet, it doesn't work, as the onPress function seems like empty !!!!!

Comment: Can you add your current code, including the changes and `onPress`? I use exactly the same and it works for me.

Comment: I have posted the edits within update in the native post above, please check it

Comment: 'OpenFilex.open(...)' is `async`, do have to `await` it. `createExcel()` is also `async`, you have to `await` it in `onPress` and mark `onPress` as `async`. I don't see the code for `AddSaveButton`, so I don't know what it does.

Comment: Ofcourse I tried with async and await, unfortunatelly it's the same.
Actually I don't know what is the reason!!!
For the 'AddSaveButton' it's simple statelessWidget I had made it, it contains materialButton and some properties like (font , color, height, width , etc..) I use it as a reusable widget.
Anyway, Thank you alot for your interest, but hope to see the final solution

Comment: Kotali
I think my problem is about the openFile package either the open_filex which you told me about it.
I put the required lines in Manafist.xml & build.gradle, and give permessions for external storage, but the same result

Answer (score 0):

For workaround, put workbook.dispose(); in try catch block.

```
try { 
  workbook.dispose()

} catch(e) {
  print(e)
}
```